# PhotoChooserTask how to pass extra parameter Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Say I have this code

```
private void photoChooserBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    photoChooserTask = new PhotoChooserTask();
    photoChooserTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult (photoChooserTask_Completed);
    photoChooserTask.Show();
}

private void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
         BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
         bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
         imagecontrol.Source = bmp;
    }
}
```

I have to repeat this code several times as I have several buttons. I want to avoid this.

I want to have one button click event. Then append extra parameter to photoChooserTask so that I can process the result in `photoChooserTask_Completed` event based on the parameter.

So in `photoChooserBtn_Click` event. I would like to do something like this.

```
Button btn = (Button)sender;
photoChooserTask.Tag = btn.Name;
```

Then

```
private void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
         BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
         bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
         imagecontrol.Source = bmp;
         string param = ((PhotoChooserTask)sender).Tag;

         Switch (param)
         {
            case "bla":
            case "bla2":
          ...........   

    }
}
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is not possible. However you can add a string tag property to your page. Since only one PhotoChooserTask can run at a time, this approach should be fine.

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    string tag;

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void photoChooserBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        photoChooserTask = new PhotoChooserTask();
        tag = (sender as Button).Name;
        photoChooserTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(photoChooserTask_Completed);
        photoChooserTask.Show();
    }

    private void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
            bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
            imagecontrol.Source = bmp;

            switch(tag)
            {
                case tag1:
                case tag2:
                ........
            }

            tag = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: why I didn't think of that. I guess I was trying hard not to introduce a class level variable..